# Using checkboxes to update UI in realtime

Tags: javascript, checkbox

I'm currently in the process of trying to develop a smarter UI for one of my clients. However the only code I can use to develop this 'feature', is pure JS. I have no access to the source HTML or CSS files the only access I have is the ability to inject JavaScript through an external .js file.
I'm not too familiar with JS, but I can work my way around a basic script or two.

**Scenario**

What we're doing is allowing users to edit PDF Templates online using a software called Core Create. The UI accessed through the browser is quite cluttered and I would like to provide an option to hide and show UI elements `<textareas>/<inputs>` through the use of checkboxes.

> Here is a very basic [**JS Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/dwvLtzt7/30/) that I have built with the
>   intention of hiding and displaying UI.

**The page in question**

[image]

Above is a screen grab of the page I am working with, on the left you can see the UI and its composition on the right within the 'Inspect Element' tool.

I have come to the conclusion that I need to iterate through the highlighted selection and link them accordingly with seven checkboxes. The result would then be a selection of checkboxes that would hide / display the correct UI element.

**The Caveat**

In realizing I cannot edit or introduce new HTML I noticed the lack of on-click attributes. So I'm a bit lost on how to invoke the JavaScript I will eventually build.

> **My Question**
>
> With my limited knowledge of JS I don't know how I would iterate though div elements `editoraccvar - editoraccvar6` picking out the ones I need to manipulate.
>
> Due to the lack of ID's / Names (I assume it would have to be done using Parent/Child rules somehow, as the classes are widley used by the rest of the UI. I would appreciate a small example demonstrating how I could achieve this, so I can learn from it.

*I should clarify, I have already added the checkboxes to the page, I just need to build the JS link between the Checkbox and the UI element I'm attempting to target. You can find all attributes linking to these checkboxes included in the [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dwvLtzt7/30/).*

**EDIT // A Working Simplified Example;**

*Due to some confusion I have 'frankensteined' some code together to show the final result I am after. A working example of sorts. The actual result needs to target 7 Checkboxes and 7 Divisions. I'll list thier common properties below.*

```js
// This script is already in place and constructed by the system.
// Written inside script tags and located straight after 'editopt1'.
//    $(document).ready(function() {
//      $('#checkboxopt1').click(function() {
//        if ($('#checkboxopt1').val() == 'true') {
//          $('#opt1').val('false');
//          $('#checkboxopt1').val('false');
//          $('#checkboxopt1').prop('checked', false);
//          $('#previewrefresh').trigger('click');
//        } else {
//          $('#opt1').val('true');
//          $('#checkboxopt1').val('true');
//          $('#checkboxopt1').prop('checked', true);
//          $('#previewrefresh').trigger('click');
//        };
//      });
//    });

function exFunction() {

  // Check the function is called
  console.log("200 : OK");

  // grab all elements with the class, .field-summernote
  var uiblocks = document.querySelectorAll('.field-summernote');

  for (var i = 0; i < uiblocks.length; i++) {

    var current = uiblocks[i];
    if (current.className.indexOf('editoraccvar') < 0) //not found: -1
      return;

    // check elements in the array
    console.log(current);

    // control the elemets in the array.
    if (document.getElementById('checkboxopt1').checked) {
      uiblocks[0].style.display = 'block'; // display the element
    } else {
      uiblocks[0].style.display = 'none'; // hide the element
    }
  }
};

// Trigger the collection the check, and the control.
var x = document.getElementById("checkboxopt1");
x.addEventListener("click", function() {
  console.log("Opt");
  exFunction();
});
```

```css
.editoraccvar1 {
  width: 300px;
  background: #0ff;
  padding: .5em;
}
.editoropt1 {
  width: 300px;
  background: #ff0;
  padding: .5em;
}
textarea {
  display: block;
  width: 95%;
  resize: none;
  padding: .5em;
}
```

```html
<!-- I'm trying to hide & show this entire division... -->
<div class="seq-box-form-field  field-summernote editoraccvar1  ">
  <label for="accvar1">Ground Floor Info</label>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
  <textarea id="richaccvar1" name="richaccvar1" class="summernote"></textarea>
  <input type="hidden" name="accvar1" id="accvar1" value="" />
</div>

<!-- Using only what the system has supplied. -->
<div class="seq-box-form-field  editoropt1  ">
  <label for="opt1"><span style="padding-right: 10px; vertical-align: 1px;">Ground Floor </span>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxopt1" id="checkboxopt1" value="true" checked="true" />
    <input type="hidden" name="opt1" id="opt1" value="true" />
  </label>
</div>
```

> Divisions `<div class=""></div>`
>   * editoraccvar,
>   editoraccvar1,
>   editoraccvar2,
>   editoraccvar3,
>   editoraccvar4,
>   editoraccvar5,
>   editoraccvar6*
>
> Checkboxes `<input id=""></input>`
>   * checkboxopt,
>   checkboxopt1,
>   checkboxopt2,
>   checkboxopt3,
>   checkboxopt4,
>   checkboxopt5,
>   checkboxopt6,*

Comment: Try invoking document.querySelectorAll("div[class^='editoraccvar']") and see if that gets you each div

Comment: @RobertParham that bad huh? lol

Comment: @LukeP I had thought about using classes to target the div's that I needed, but I assumed you would need to query each unique class. I.e `editoraccvar1, editoraccvar2, & so on...`.

Comment: @Beaniie - no, not bad at all, was just surprised to see scenario misspelled by such an otherwise well spoken poster..

Comment: @Robert Parham I genuinely thought it was spelled as such... lol

Comment: Your assumption that you cannot introduce new HTML or edit HTML is wrong. Javascript does everything and more of what HTML does. I want to help you but I can't quite understand your requirements. Do checkboxes or the fields you want to hide exist before you inject your script? The fields you want to hide, do they share a common property (`field-summernote` class is it or they each has an id that starts with `editoraccvar`)?

Comment: @Gökhan Kurt I can understand your difficulty in understanding the given task but I wouldn't say the fact that I cannot add HTML is wrong I would refer to it as more difficult. Due to the lack of access to these source files, should I add an element through javascript, I would create rather large gap for error. Due to my lack of knowledge with JS I cannot just add things in willy nilly without first understanding the scope of the task at hand and what resources I have at my desposal. Which is why I have approached this open forum.

Comment: To answer your questions, yes the checkboxes already exist they are generated by the software as is thier attributes, I can only use what the software defines, The only common property is thier `name="checkboxopt"` however, this name is incremented. I.e. `name="checkboxopt1", name="checkboxopt2"`. Regarding editor accvar, this is a page section containing all information related to the fields I'm trying to hide, for example, the label, the text area, the rich text formatting controls etc. This is shown in my illustrated example, The divisions highlighted are what Im looking to control.

Comment: @Beaniie Can you check my answer. You can comment there if you have further requirements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can see, your problem boils down to link checkboxes (that seem to have been generated in some way) to "division" parts of your html that you want to hide. Plus, you have to inject javascript code in the page (so I guess the less code the better).

One approach could be as follows:

```
// Wrap the code in an anonymus function, to avoid clustering the global space.
(function (domElements) {
    // This is the callback that will fire when a checkbox is clicked.
    function clickCallback() {
        // the context of this callback is the DOM element thus we can access its attributes through this.
        // extract the checkNumber of the class of the element. This number is the link to the division that we want to hide/show.
        var checkNumber = ((/ editoropt(\d*) /).exec(this.className))[1],
            checkBox = document.getElementById('checkboxopt' + checkNumber),
            division = document.querySelectorAll('.editoraccvar' + checkNumber)[0];

        // Hide/show division, update checkBox state.
        toggleElements(division, checkBox, window.getComputedStyle(division).display === 'none');
    }

    function toggleElements(division, checkBox, isShown) {
        // Toggle the division (show/hide) accordingly.
        division.style.display = isShown ? 'block' : 'none';
        // Due to the fact that the event listener is attached to the parent of the checkBox, we need to maintain consistency manually.
        checkBox.checked = isShown;
    }

    // Remove from the array of DOMElements those that aren't checkboxes and add a click event listener to each of them.
    domElements
            .filter(function (el) {
                return el.className.indexOf('editoropt') !== -1;
            })
            .forEach(function (el) {
                el.addEventListener('click', clickCallback, false);
            });

// Call the function passing the dom elements with class '.seq-box-form-field' as argument. Checkboxes are contained within them. Also, transform the nodelist
// into a proper array so that methods defined in Array.prototype can be used.
})([].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.seq-box-form-field')));
```

The code is commented and (I think) quite self-explanatory. However, if you have any doubt or want me to elaborate any point further, please, let me know.

Finally, here's the working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dwvLtzt7/35/).

**UPDATE**

Same function (more or less) but now it accepts an array of values that will correspond to the initial state of the checkboxes:

```
(function (domElements, cbState) {
    function clickCallback() {
        toggleElements(this.className);
    }

    function toggleElements(className, initialShow) {
        var checkNumber = ((/ editoropt(\d*) /).exec(className))[1],
            checkBox = document.getElementById('checkboxopt' + checkNumber),
            division = document.querySelectorAll('.editoraccvar' + checkNumber)[0],
            isShown = initialShow === undefined ? window.getComputedStyle(division).display === 'none' : initialShow;

        division.style.display = isShown ? 'block' : 'none';
        checkBox.checked = isShown;
    }

    domElements
            .filter(function (el) {
                return el.className.indexOf('editoropt') !== -1;
            })
            .forEach(function (el, index) {
                el.addEventListener('click', clickCallback, false);
                toggleElements(el.className, cbState[index]);
            });

// Initial state of the checkboxes goes in the second parameter. The index in the array correspond to the checkbox position in the page.
})([].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.seq-box-form-field')), [false, false]);
```

Here's the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dwvLtzt7/40/) to play with. Hope it helps.

Comment: Your answer has elightened me more than you can imagine, the amount of hair you just saved me yanking out is incredible.  Thank you for your time on this. I must ask though within the `function toggleElements(division, checkBox, isShown)`, you mention maintaining consistancy, could you elaborate?

Comment: Thanks @Beaniie! Sure, let me elaborate. The thing is, the event listener is attached to the parent element of the checkBox. This means that, if I click in the parent (not exactly the checkbox but the div that contains it) the toggle action is going to trigger. However, the checkbox will not change its state due to the fact that we didn't click it. Thus (and due to consistency) we have to manually set it to its correct state so that it can appear checked/unchecked accordingly. Hope this clarifies things. Any more questions are welcomed :)

Comment: I rememeber reading an article relating to a similar issue, However I couldn't quite visualise the problem. So essentially your code is targeting the entire element to avoid the event listening all the way up the DOM Tree?

Comment: Events bubble up the DOM tree (all the way up unless you explicitly stop them in an event handler). This is really a good thing because it allows us to handle events in parent elements without having to explicitly add the same event handler to every subelement. Taking advantage of this, I added the click event handler to the div containing the checkbox. This is usually better than controlling the click on the checkbox itself (sometimes users don't click exactly on the checkbox but some element surrounding it). Controlling the event in the parent guarantees that those clicks don't go unhandled.

Comment: I see, my final question to you good sir'. Is it possible to determine the elements `isShown` on DOM load? for example if I want to preset some checkboxes as checked and some as unchecked, could the function be triggered on DOM load to hide the elements from the get go? I did assume I could just fire the clicks on load but that didn't quite work.  :(

Comment: Yes, no problem. We could pass an array to the function that indicates the state of the checkboxes. The length of the array would be the number of checkboxes and the value, true or false, its state. If the value is true, the division appears and the checkbox is checked (false, the contrary). We could perform the logic in the function that sets the events handlers. If it's ok with you, I can update the answer with this solution (you'd only have to set the array to whatever values you see fit).

Comment: Just what I was looking for, A litle bit of tinkering and the addition of a basic if statment to check a default option and I have lift off. Thank you once again on your unparalleled support on this. I will continue to update my code as I make improvements so others that stumble accross this thread will also be enlightened. :)

Comment: If I wanted to add `var total = 0;`, and have it so that **if** a checkbox is checked it increases the total by `30`. How would I do so? would I add it into `foreach` or into `clickCallback`?

Comment: @Beaniie it depends on what you have in mind (increase/decrease when it's checked/unchecked?). What about creating another post with that question? It's getting a bit messy in here (you can link me in a comment or post the link here so that I can check it out). Thanks.

Comment: here's the link to the new thread. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39902887/using-checkboxes-to-contol-an-input-value-with-a-annoying-twist)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like that you need the elements that have the class "field-summernote", but not the class "editorbdyvar".

You can use a query selector to get elements by class name using the default tools from Javascript:

```
var items = document.querySelectorAll('.field-summernote');

for(var i = 0; i<items.length; i++){

  var current = items[i];
  if( current.className.indexOf('editoraccvar') < 0) //not found: -1
    return;

  //now you can manipulate the current element
  console.log(current);

}
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to provide an example, the class `.field-summernote` is actually the styling of all the text area elements targeting this would in-turn target every text area element on the page. However, adjusting your example to target `editoraccvar` to `editoraccvar6`. It may work.

Comment: You can force a child-parent relation in the selector: `.seq-box-form .field-summernote`. This way only the summernotes that are children of the seq-box-form class will be selected.

Comment: I understand you are saying that I can narrow my operating field to just the elements within the `.seq-box-form-(div)`. However if I use, `.field-summernote.` wouldn't that mean that I would also in-turn be targeting, `.editorbdyvar, .editorsitvar & .editorbluvar`? I do not wish to edit these.

Comment: I edited the response, now only elements with a class named editoraccvar* will be used

Comment: This particular slice of code hits the nail on the head when pulling the specific divs that I need to manipulate. I appeciate your contribution and example. However I still need to address the link between my Checkboxes and these elements.

Comment: I have update the fiddle with a custom approach, it can be optimized but it should be enough for now: https://jsfiddle.net/25sdv9bh/15/

Answer (score 1):

The other half of your problem, not addressed in the other answer has to do with events. Generally, adding an "onclick" attribute to the actual HTML is considered bad practice. You can attach event handlers with Javascript.

```
var a = document.getElementById("checkboxopt1");
a.addEventListener("click", exFunction, false);
```

See [the manual](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) for more info about how to use this.

Comment: For readers following along, this answer provided by Robet Parham, is indeed the correct answer to a portion of my problem, I can now invoke my javascript directly, via an `eventListener`.

Answer (score 1):

well ... you should either learn javascript, DOM, HTML and CSS or hire an somebody that can do it.
in my opinion the latter would come cheaper.

if not, 
here goes something to put in your script.js file.

the checkboxes must have the id="toggleTextareas" respectively id="toggleInputs".

```
(function isolateScope() {

tryInit();

function tryInit() {
    if(document.readyState!="complete"){
        setTimeout(tryInit, 100);
    }else{
        createUI();
        init();
    }
}

function createUI(){
      var div=document.createElement("div");
      div.className="addon-floating-toolbar"
      div.style.position="fixed";
      div.style.zIndex="999999";
      div.style.background="#EEE";
      div.style.padding="5px";

      div.innerHTML='<input type="checkbox" id="toggleTextareas">toggle Textareas<br>'
          +'<input type="checkbox" id="toggleInputs">toggle Inputs';

      document.body.appendChild(div);

   }

function init() {
    var tta=document.getElementById("toggleTextareas");
    var ti=document.getElementById("toggleInputs");

    var textareaVisible=true;
    var inputVisible=true;

    tta.onclick=toggleTextareas;
    ti.onclick=toggleInputs;

    function toggleTextareas() {
        var elms=document.querySelectorAll("textarea");
        textareaVisible=!textareaVisible;
        if (textareaVisible) {
            show(elms);
        }else{
            hide(elms);
        }
    }

    function toggleInputs() {
        var elms=document.querySelectorAll("input");
        inputVisible=!inputVisible;
        if (inputVisible) {
            show(elms);
        }else{
            hide(elms);
        }
    }

    function show(collection) {
        for (var i = 0; i < collection.length; i++) {
            collection[i].style.display="";
        }
    }

    function hide(collection) {
        for (var i = 0; i < collection.length; i++) {
            collection[i].style.display="none";
        }
    }
}

})();
```

let me know if it works,
cheers.

Comment: Thank you for your response and example, sadly hireing out would not be possible for the scope of the singular task but we may be evaluating this in the future.

Comment: There was an error at setTimeout, i fixed it. Don't forget to test it and bump my answer up .... :)

Comment: Sadly I don't have access to the source HTML in this case, as mentioned in the question. Which would mean that I can't introduce your solution, unless it can be introduced using the tags provided.

Comment: added a function to create the UI, and append it to the page after the page had loaded.

Comment: Thanks for amending your answer, I have already placed the UI on the page through the software that I am using. Please take a look at the updated Fiddle link in the question as it illustrates the elments and thier Identifier attributes I have access to. I cannot ammend these attributes. I also need to add event listeners to each checkbox Item.

Comment: Further understanding the scope of my issue I now understand that I probably need to place the checkboxes into an array too and link both arrays together to acheive an independent response, I.e. I check zero, only text area zero is hidden.

Answer (score 1):

You can traverse all your fields and generate a checkbox that will toggle it open/close for each of your fields. Also set the checkbox label as `innerText` of the corresponding field.

```js
// Block to be run
generateCheckboxes = function() {
  var button = document.getElementById("generateButton");
  button.parentNode.removeChild(button);
  // grab all elements with the class, .field-summernote
  var uiblocks = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.field-summernote')).filter(function(x) {
    return x.className.indexOf('editoraccvar') >= 0
  });
  if (!uiblocks.length) return;

  var chcontainer = document.createElement('div');
  chcontainer.style.display = "inline-block";
  document.body.insertBefore(chcontainer, document.body.children[0]);
  uiblocks.forEach(function(x) {
    var cdiv = document.createElement('div');
    var clabel = document.createElement('label');
    clabel.innerHTML = x.innerText.trim();
    var cinput = document.createElement('input');
    cinput.type = 'checkbox';
    cinput.checked = true;
    cinput.onchange = function(ev) {
      var checked = this.checked;
      x.style.display = checked ? "" : "none";
    }
    cdiv.appendChild(clabel);
    cdiv.appendChild(cinput);
    cdiv.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
    chcontainer.appendChild(cdiv);
  })
};
```

```css
#container {
  width: 150px;
}
input {
  float: left;
}
label {
  width: 120px;
  display: block;
  float: right;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="generateCheckboxes()" id="generateButton">Generate Checkboxes</button>

<div id="example" class="field-summernote editoraccvar">
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <span>Zero</span>
  <br/>
  <textarea></textarea>
</div>

<div id="example1" class="field-summernote editoraccvar1">
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <span>One</span>
  <br/>
  <textarea></textarea>
</div>
<div id="example2" class="field-summernote">
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <span>Two</span>
  <br/>
  <textarea></textarea>
</div>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zr9wh3ad/2)

Comment: There is an undefined error. `Error: {
  "message": "TypeError: ev is undefined",
  "filename": "http://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 52,
  "colno": 3
} `.

Comment: @Beaniie Looks like an error caused by IE. Fixed the code so it works on IE.

Comment: This result is very VERY close to what I'm after, I have updated my question with a working example of a very simplified version. Please take a look I've tried to explain myself in the best way I know possible, (Side note I don't need to generate the checkboxes they are already listed on the page.)