# Using Checkboxes to contol an Input.value (With an annoying twist.)

Tags: javascript, performance

I've been researching for a few days methods of controlling UI with checkboxes and with the help of some members on Stack' I've come really quite far. But my balding doesn't quite stop yet. I've been trying to further tweak my code snippet, by including a numeric value alongside my UI controller. (This value will be of use later inside the web-java applet.)

> For example, when a checkbox is checked `var total` is ammended from `0` to `30`. If a Checkbox is unchecked the value returns to '0'.

[(Main Build JS Fiddle)](https://jsfiddle.net/dwvLtzt7/56/), 
[(Checkbox Example)](https://jsfiddle.net/dwvLtzt7/54/).

The second fiddle allows the use of data attributes, however these will need to be injected into the HTML via, JS. As like before I have '**NO**' access to the CSS or HTML source files.

> [**(Original Post)**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39792899/using-checkboxes-to-update-ui-in-realtime)
>   *- This post is a follow on from another question asked here on stack, due to the nature of the question changing, and the comments getting fairly confusing I was asked to open a new thread.*

Below I'll post two snippets, one is of the original build, built with the aid of user [@acontell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3565885/acontell). The other is an example of the type of result I am after, built with the aid of, user [@Rajesh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3783478/rajesh). Link to [(Example Source)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39897893/simplifying-combining-if-statement-logic-when-using-numbers).

---

**The Base Build**

```js
// Control UI...
(function(domElements, cbState) {

  // Number increment
  var total = 0 + ' mm';
  document.getElementById('adjvar').value = total;

  function clickCallback() {
    toggleElements(this.className);
  }

  function toggleElements(className, initialShow) {
    var checkNumber = ((/ editoropt(\d*) /).exec(className))[1],
      checkBox = document.getElementById('checkboxopt' + checkNumber),
      division = document.querySelectorAll('.editoraccvar' + checkNumber)[0],
      isShown = initialShow === undefined ? window.getComputedStyle(division).display === 'none' : initialShow;

    division.style.display = isShown ? 'block' : 'none';
    checkBox.checked = isShown;


    // ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
    // increment count...
    var val = 30;
    total += (+val * (checkBox.checked ? 1 : -1));
    document.getElementById('adjvar').value = total + ' mm';
    document.getElementsByClassName('adjvar').value = checkBox.checked ? val : 0 + ' mm';
    // ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++


  }

  domElements
    .filter(function(el) {
      return el.className.indexOf('editoropt') !== -1;
    })
    .forEach(function(el, index) {
      el.addEventListener('click', clickCallback, false);
      toggleElements(el.className, cbState[index]);
    });

})([].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.seq-box-form-field')), [false, false]);

// Default Checked...

if (document.getElementById('checkboxopt').checked) {
  // do nothing
} else {
  document.getElementById('checkboxopt').click();
}

// inject style
function ctSe() {
  var css = "input[type='checkbox'] { float:left; margin-right: 1em !important;}",
    head = document.head || document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0],
    style = document.createElement('style');

  style.type = 'text/css';
  if (style.styleSheet) {
    style.styleSheet.cssText = css;
  } else {
    style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(css));
  }

  head.appendChild(style);
  console.log(head)
  console.log(style)
  console.log(css)
};

ctSe();
```

```css
.editoraccvar {
  width: 300px;
  background: #f0f;
  padding: .5em;
}
.editoropt {
  width: 300px;
  background: #0f0;
  padding: .5em;
}
.editoraccvar1 {
  width: 300px;
  background: #0ff;
  padding: .5em;
}
.editoropt1 {
  width: 300px;
  background: #ff0;
  padding: .5em;
}
textarea {
  display: block;
  width: 95%;
  resize: none;
  padding: .5em;
}
```

```html
<!-- I'm trying to hide & show this entire division... -->
<div class="seq-box-form-field  field-summernote editoraccvar  ">
  <label for="accvar1">Ground Floor Info</label>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
  <textarea id="richaccvar1" name="richaccvar1" class="summernote"></textarea>
  <input type="hidden" name="accvar1" id="accvar1" value="" />
</div>

<!-- Using only what the system has supplied. -->
<div class="seq-box-form-field  editoropt  ">
  <label for="opt1"><span style="padding-right: 10px; vertical-align: 1px;">Ground Floor </span>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxopt" id="checkboxopt" value="true" checked="true" />
    <input type="hidden" name="opt1" id="opt1" value="true" />
  </label>
</div>

<!-- Secondary Division -->
<div class="seq-box-form-field  field-summernote editoraccvar1  ">
  <label for="accvar1">First Floor</label>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
  <textarea id="richaccvar1" name="richaccvar1" class="summernote"></textarea>
  <input type="hidden" name="accvar1" id="accvar1" value="" />
</div>

<!-- Secondary Checkbox -->
<div class="seq-box-form-field  editoropt1  ">
  <label for="opt1"><span style="padding-right: 10px; vertical-align: 1px;">First Floor </span>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxopt1" id="checkboxopt1" value="true" checked="true" />
    <input type="hidden" name="opt1" id="opt1" value="true" />
  </label>
</div>
<input name="adjvar" id="adjvar" readonly>
```

---

**The Example**

```js
(function() {
  var total = 0;

  function calculate(index) {
    var el = document.getElementsByClassName('checkbox-input')[index];
    var val = el.getAttribute("data-value");
    total += (+val * (el.checked ? 1 : -1));
    document.getElementById('pnvar').value = total;
    document.getElementsByClassName('pnvar')[index].value = el.checked ? val : 0;
  }

  function registerEvents() {
    var cbs = document.querySelectorAll('[type="checkbox"]');
    [].forEach.call(cbs, function(cb, i) {
      cb.addEventListener("click", function() {
        calculate(i);
      });
    });

    document.getElementById('pnvar').addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
      if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        event.preventDefault();
        return false;
      }
    })
  }

  window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    registerEvents();
    calculate(0)
  })
})()
```

```css
.editoropt {
  font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;
  width: 160px;
  background: #f8f8ff;
  padding: .5em;
  border: solid 1px #ddd;
}
#checkboxopt {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 1em;
  margin-top: 4px;
}
#checkboxopt1 {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 1em;
  margin-top: 4px;
}
.pnvar {
  width: 95%;
}
input:-moz-read-only {
  /* For Firefox */
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  border-width: 0px;
}
input:read-only {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  border-width: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="seq-box-form-field  editoropt  ">
  <label for="opt1">
    <span style="padding-right: 10px; vertical-align: 1px;">Default 80mm </span>
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-input" data-value="80" name="checkboxopt" id="checkboxopt" value="true" checked />
    <input type="hidden" name="opt1" id="opt1" value="true" />
  </label>
</div>
<div class="seq-box-form-field  editoropt  ">
  <label for="opt1">
    <span style="padding-right: 10px; vertical-align: 1px;">Add 30mm </span>
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-input" name="checkboxopt1" data-value="30" id="checkboxopt1" value="true" />
    <input type="hidden" name="opt2" id="opt2" value="true" />
  </label>
</div>
<div class="editoropt">
  <input id="pnvar" name="pnvar" placeholder="Null" onkeydown="" value="" class="required" type="text">
  <input name="adjvar" class="pnvar" id="adjvar" readonly value="0">
  <input name="adjvar" class="pnvar" id="adjvar2" readonly value="0">
</div>
```

---

As I mentioned in my previous post, I'm not a JS Whizz and I'm just finding my feet, however I am abitious to learn and further my knowledge. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

*Note : All tags, classes and names, must remain the same for consistancy with another application.*

Comment: Soooooo.... what's not working? What is the annoying twist?

Comment: @Zack, The annoying twist is mentioned at the bottom in the note and the first snippet is the one that is broken, I'm unsure basically on how to properly merge the two. I did try but the value repeats, it reacts nothing like the example snippet.

Comment: What value repeats? You have so many snippets here, which one are you referring to by "the example snippet"?

Comment: Apologies if I have overcrowded the question, I just wanted to be as detailed as possible. :( The Original Snippet is repeating the value, i used some of the structure of the example snippet in there.

Comment: You're still not providing any detail as to what value is repeating by saying "The Original Snippet is repeating the value". *what value?* Is it some JavaScript var that has a name that you can provide?

Comment: Ohhh my apologies, it's been a long day. the  `document.getElementsByClassName('adjvar').value = checkBox.checked ? val : 0 + ' mm';` line appears to be outputing a repeated value into var `total`. when you run the snippet and look at the `adjvar.value` after clicking a checkbox a few times you will see a repeated value. Where as in the example, check a checkbox you get `30`, uncheck a checkbox you get `0`.

Comment: All you care about is "when the checkbox underneath the div checked state changes, it should hide the div when unchecked, and show the div when checked" is that basically what you need? The text box in your snippets is just for some kind of unexplained debugging you were trying?

Comment: @Beaniie I see that there's one division hidden and the other shown by default, what is the initial value of the input then? 30 mm? When both divisions are hidden, is the value 0? Thanks

Comment: @acontell, I understand why you asked this now, and also included the safegaurd. This value can change depending on my needs but I'll do this manually, hense my original variable of `total` or more specifically `var total = '0';`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might be mistaken but I think that this two lines of code:

```
// Default Checked...

if (document.getElementById('checkboxopt').checked) {
    // do nothing
} else {
    document.getElementById('checkboxopt').click();
}
```

Could be avoided if you passed `[true, false]` as the initial states of the checkboxes:

```
([].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.seq-box-form-field')), [true, false]);
```

I might be wrong, you might be doing something else or the state of the page could require that click, I don't know.

Going back to the issue, if you want to increase/decrease by 30 when the checkbox is checked/unchecked, you could do as follows:

Create a function that retrieves the value of the input an updates it with a quantity added to it. The value of the input is a string of the form 'x mm' so a bit of tinkering is necessary to get the integer part of the value.

```
function updateInputValue(n) {
    var actual = +document.getElementById('adjvar').value.split(' mm')[0] || 0;
    document.getElementById('adjvar').value = (actual + n) + ' mm';
}
```

Inside `toggleElement` call this function in order to update the input value.

```
var increment = isShown ? 30 : -30;
updateInputValue(initialShow === undefined ? increment : +initialShow * 30);
```

It gets a bit complicated because you have to control the initial state of the inputs, but it's not that hard: if it's the initial state, initialShow is different from undefined so we transform the value (it's a boolean) into a number a multiply it by 30 (when it's checked, it'd be 1 * 30, when it's unchecked it'd be 0 * 30). When it's not the initial state, we increment/decrement depending on whether it's checked or not.

And here's the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dwvLtzt7/57/) (I also commented out the part that clicked the checkbox). Hope it helps.

Comment: Once again good sir you have outdone yourself! I do have a few questions so please bare with me as I go through your amendment. :)

Comment: I understand that `.split` will split a sting of `var str ='Hello World!';` into; `// "Hello, World!"`. However I'm struggling to understand the logic behind, `.split(' mm')[0] || 0;` Wouldn't this cause the output to be `mm 30`?

Comment: If possible could you elaborate on how adding `[true, false]`, to `([].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.seq-box-form-field')));` works in principle.

Comment: @Beaniie split transforms a string into an array of strings and uses the separator you pass to it as an argument to do so. As I know that the string has the form "x mm", I assume I will get an array which first element will be "x" (it explains the [0] part). I then transform the string into a number (the '+' at the beginning). It's possible that this transformation is applied over a non-numeric value (empty input, for instance, ""). When this happens, the transformation will return NaN. To avoid this NaN I apply a guard ( || 0) to make sure a numeric value is always assigned to the variable.

Comment: All the code is wrapped into a function that is immediately executed (google IIFE) with two arguments. These two arguments are: an array of  DOM elements and the initial state of the checkboxes. This initial state is an array where the index corresponds to the number of the checkbox and the value is its state (true: checked, false: unchecked). When the function executes, it sets the initial state of the checkboxes based on this array (there's a toggleElements(el.className, cbState[index]); that sets the initial state)

Comment: So if 'm understanding correctly, `x` is the first element of an array [0], which is then converted into `numeric value via '+document.`. This could return a empty value such as `NaN`. So you've included a safe guard of `0`. So if NaN is found, `|| 0;` will input `0`.

Comment: In theory `|| 0` is the initial value or finding. So if I were to adjust `|| 0;` to `|| 150;`. the outcome of a checkbox click would be `180 mm`?

Comment: 150 would be the initial value. I mean, the first time we try to get the value of the input "".split(" mm") will return [""]. Getting the first value of [""] ([""][0]) will return "", converting "" to number will return NaN and then NaN || 150 will finally return 150. And then we apply the addition/substraction. However, next clicks (or next accesses to the value of the input) will be: "x mm".split(" mm") === ["x"], ["x"][0] === x; +x = x; and x || 150 === x

Comment: I think my brain just exploded.  What you are saying is that the 'First' finding would be `'0'`.  Then it's amended to `'150'`. Followed by the addition/subtraction. You've lost me on the last part specifically here, `"x mm".split(" mm") === ["x"]`.

Comment: (edit time ran out. :| ) Could you elaborate on the `===['x']` part.

Comment: I think the best way to learn all this would be using the browser console and playing with split and some of the things we were talking, hopefully it'll throw some light in the matter. Maybe some console.log in the code would also help you to understand how things are working under the covers. In essence, there are some things that I did in order to reduce the number of lines of code. However, doing that increased a bit the complexity and readability of the code... by the way, "x mm".split(" mm") returns ["x", ""], sorry about that

Comment: I will admit understanding how it's operating through `console.log()` may help a great deal. In addition, what you have done to reduce the lines of code, resulting in a decreased readability; is an area I'm quite interested in. I'm just not too farmiliar with all of the operators and syntax of more complex coding. Your example is prooving to be a good learning example.